# Code-style for indention of multi-line 'if' statement?

Tags: python, coding-style, indentation, code-readability

When indenting long if conditions, you usually do something like this (actually, PyDev indents like that):

```
if (collResv.repeatability is None or
    collResv.somethingElse):
    collResv.rejected = True
    collResv.rejectCompletely()
```

However, this puts the block started by the if statement on the same indentation level as the last part of the if condition which makes it very ugly/hard to read in my opinion as you don't immediately see where the block starts.

Some other styles I thought about:

```
if (collResv.repeatability is None or
        collResv.somethingElse):
    collResv.rejected = True
    collResv.rejectCompletely()
```

This looks pretty inconsistent as the second line is indented much more than the first line but it's readable.

```
if (collResv.repeatability is None or
  collResv.somethingElse):
    collResv.rejected = True
    collResv.rejectCompletely()
```

This is also more readable than the first example, but the indentation is not a multiple of 4 anymore and besides that it looks wrong as the second line has less indentation than the beginning of the condition in the first line.

---

So, my main question is: Is there a suggested indentation style for cases like that which do not require overly-long lines (i.e. a single-line condition)?
If not, what do *you* prefer for cases like that?

Comment: Why isn't there a method on `collResv` to do the test? The fact that you have to do a compound condition on something that isn't `self` may indicate you need to refactor. Likewise why doesn't a method called `rejectCompletely()` also set the `rejected` attribute on the object?

Comment: Actually that was just an example. there is no method with that name - i just wanted something sounding a bit sensible to have more than one line in the body.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is an indirect answer--not answering the style question directly, but it's the practical answer in general, so it's worth mentioning.

I find it extremely rare to need to write multi-line conditionals.  There are two factors to this:

- Don't wrap code at 80 columns.  PEP-8's advice on this subject is ancient and harmful; we're well past the days of 80x25 terminals and editors that can't sensibly handle wrapping.  100 columns is fine, and 120 is usually acceptable, too.
- If conditions become so long that they still need to wrap, it's usually reasonable to move some of the logic out of the conditional and into a separate expression.  This also tends to help readability.

Grepping through my recent projects, around 12kloc, there's only one conditional long enough that it needed to be wrapped; the issue simply very rarely arises.  If you do need to do this, then as nosklo says, indent it separately--as you noticed, indenting it to the same level as the block beneath it is confusing and hard to read.

Comment: Generally I agree, though there are still good reasons to stick to 80 columns (eyes prefer text with a limited width; possibility to work with multiple files side-by-side).

Comment: @Oben: That's a formatting principle for paragraphs, not code.  When you wrap English paragraphs at a certain width, *every line* is around that width; this makes wide formatting hard to read because your eyes are constantly scanning the whole width.  By contrast, when you wrap code at 120 columns, most lines are much shorter; there are just a few isolated lines which are longer.  The readability issues associated with too-wide paragraphs don't occur.

Comment: I don't find the "side-by-side" case interesting--two 80-column editors don't even fit on my 24" monitor at a comfortable font size, and in any case wrapping at 80 columns uglifies code so badly it's just not worth it.  People can live with a bit of editor wrapping if they're in that configuration, rather than expecting everyone else to squish their code.

Comment: Yes, a limited with is more important for continuous text. Still, I (respectively my eyes) prefer this principle for code too - but obviously this is a personal preference.

Comment: As soon as one dev uses superlong lines - thinking that 200-char lines or whatever don't have to wrap on today's screens - some other developer now can't put three windows side-by-side on a monitor and see reasonably formatted code.  More than 80 cols is essentially the same as inflicting unwrapped code on other devs - it has nothing to do with prose text.  Just because a given author can't put two 80 column editors side by side doesn't mean no one else will want to (although some devs needing a large font size to read easily is a good argument against long functions... AND long lines)

Comment: The 80 lines constraint is explicitly stated in the google formatting guide for python: https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html#Indentation which is widely used across many different communities.

Answer (score 29):

Often I work around this problem by calculating the condition in an own statement:

```
condition = (collResv.repeatability is None or
             collResv.somethingElse)
if condition:
    collResv.rejected = True
    collResv.rejectCompletely()
```

Though, for a still relatively short condition as in your specific example I'd go for *nosklo*'s solution - the extra statement used here is more suited for even longer conditional expressions.

Comment: I think that code makes things less readable. There's really a variable just to avoid a multi-line if?!

Comment: The readability of this approach depends -- as often -- on your particular situation and of course is highly subjective. Besides that, I wouldn't care about the extra variable issue. After all that's what variables are there for: use short names for more complex things. Extra bonus: when debugging your code, some "redundant" variables come in handy.

Comment: The only time where this really makes sense is if your condition is reusable, otherwise this is mostly lazy. you could have a function that is something like `is_valid_thing` and then use that for your control flow.

Answer (score 18):

This is what I do:

```
if (collResv.repeatability is None or
        collResv.somethingElse):
    collResv.rejected = True
    collResv.rejectCompletely()
```

Answer (score 11):

One problem with all previous suggestions here is that the logical operators for the subsequent conditions are put on the preceding line. Imo, that makes it less readable.

I recommend putting the logical operator on the same line as the condition it appends to the if statement.

This in my opinion, is better

```
if (None == foo
        and None == bar
        or None == foo_bar):
```

than this:

```
if (None == foo and
        None == bar or
        None == foo_bar):
```

Oracle seem to agree, see page 6, indendation: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: One of the questions asked is "...what do you prefer for cases like that?" My answer answers that question, so not just a comment.

Comment: The OP is asking about indentation.  Your "answer" is about where to put operators in multiline expressions.

Comment: It's actually not just a question about indents. The question is also about code style and legibility of code which the OP is clearly concerned about.

Comment: This is a comment not an answer and the reverse is actually preferred, to end each line with "or", "end" or "else".

Comment: IMO, any answer whose primary reasoning is "in my opinion" is not a real answer. Unless you are a primary source qualified to make official/notable suggestions or you can cite someone/some organization who can, your opinion should be a comment.

Comment: IMO, your comment is rubbish. Anyway, I added the primary source to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I would do it this way.  Keep it indented far away not to get confused.

```
if (collResv.repeatability is None or
                          collResv.somethingElse):
    collResv.rejected = True
    collResv.rejectCompletely()
```

PEP-8 advise is right here.

http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation

Below code is advised

```
# Aligned with opening delimiter
foo = long_function_name(var_one, var_two,
                         var_three, var_four)

# More indentation included to distinguish this from the rest.
def long_function_name(
        var_one, var_two, var_three,
        var_four):
    print(var_one)
```

Below code is not advised

```
# Arguments on first line forbidden when not using vertical alignment
foo = long_function_name(var_one, var_two,
    var_three, var_four)

# Further indentation required as indentation is not distinguishable
def long_function_name(
    var_one, var_two, var_three,
    var_four):
    print(var_one)
```

Answer (score 3):

PEP-8 actually seems contradictory here.  While the example under "Maximum Line Length" shows the use of parentheses and a standard 4-character indent, the "Indentation" section says, with respect to function declarations,  "further indentation should be used to clearly distinguish itself as a continuation line.".  I don't see why this would be restricted only to "def" and not to "if".

Answer (score 0):

An option I sometimes use (although I'm not completely sold on its readability):

```
if (collResv.repeatability is None or
    collResv.somethingElse
):
    collResv.rejected = True
    collResv.rejectCompletely()
```

Possibly it would be more readable this way:

```
if (
collResv.repeatability is None or
collResv.somethingElse
):
    collResv.rejected = True
    collResv.rejectCompletely()
```

Comment: This is very unlike any Python style idiom--please don't do this.

Comment: Yeah I should note that I only use Python in simple personal projects that no-one else will ever have to read.

Comment: IMO it looks horrible no matter of the language. That's like putting only `){` on a separate line in C.

Comment: Haha, I do that too (in c#). I don't *like* it either, but I really hate all the other options :|

Answer (score 0):

Pep-8 recommends the way you indented your original example.

Now if you're willing to fly in the face of the oh so sacred of style guides :-) you could move the operator to the next line:

```
if (collResv.repeatability is None
    or collResv.somethingElse):
    collResv.rejected = True
    collResv.rejectCompletely()
```

I'm not really a fan of this, I actually find your original syntax fairly easy to read and wouldn't spend much time monkeying with the indentation or line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

In such a case, I would simply do:

```
if (collResv.repeatability is None or
    collResv.somethingElse):
    # do:
    collResv.rejected = True
    collResv.rejectCompletely()
```